# Concrete example of eigenvalues including range + discrete values

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, eigenvalue

In Dirac's *Quantum Mechanics* at p. 27 the author says that it sometimes occurs that a ket can be expressed as a range of eigenvalues plus a discrete set *including values outside the range:*

$$\vert P\rangle = \int\vert \xi'c \rangle\ d\xi' + \sum_r\vert \xi'^rd \rangle$$

Can someone give an example of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The energy of an isolated electron-proton system.

When bound the system (known as a hydrogen atom in these states) has discrete (and negative) energies, when free (ionized) the energies are continuous (and positive).

And this is a general pattern: discrete spectra tend to arise from the imposition of boundary conditions, so systems that exhibit both bound and free character tend to have mixed spectra.